# Keep only specific variables while importing a SAS Export file into R using SASxport

Tags: r, import, sas

I'm trying to import a SAS Export file into R using the SASxport library.  I can read the whole file, but cannot seem to limit the import to specific variables.  This should be possible using the "keep=" argument in read.xport; however, all the documentation I can find shows the option "keep=NULL" never with the syntax for actually using the argument.

To demonstrate, download the Demographics file from NHANES [here](https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2013-2014/DEMO_H.XPT), and save it into your working directory.

Here's the code that works:

```
test <- read.xport("DEMO_H.XPT")
```

But what I want to do is keep only four variables, using the equivalent of "(keep =seqn RIAGENDR RIDAGEYR RIDRETH1)" in SAS.  I've tried by using this syntax:

```
test <- read.xport("DEMO_H.XPT", keep =seqn RIAGENDR RIDAGEYR RIDRETH1)
```

And this one:

```
test <- read.xport("DEMO_H.XPT", keep = c("seqn", "RIAGENDR", "RIDAGEYR", "RIDRETH1"))
```

as well as a few other variations, and none work.  Can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: Per [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SASxport/versions/1.7.0/topics/read.xport), this function actually reads 1 or more datasets. So everything is at dataset level and not attributes within a single data frame. Therefore, `keep` limits dataset names not column names. How many datasets are you importing with this .xpt file? Check if `test` (without `keep`) is a single df or list of dfs.

Comment: It's a single df.  I misunderstood this fact from the documentation.  Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: So the follow-on question ... are you aware of an option that works like SAS "keep" and refers to fields, not datasets?  Or am I stuck with importing then deleting extraneous fields?

Comment: Don't know with this package. Otherwise, you would need to subset columns after import: `test <- read.xport("DEMO_H.XPT")[c("seqn", "RIAGENDR", "RIDAGEYR", "RIDRETH1")]`. Note: unlike SAS, R is case sensitive.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wound up doing, though I did it with a separate subset line.  Interestingly enough, "seqn" imports to R as "SEQN" so the case-sensitivity includes changing the case in the subset command.  Go figure ...

Comment: This method does have `names.tolower`.

Comment: So the final working line of code is
`test <- read.xport("DEMO_H.XPT")[c("SEQN", "RIAGENDR", "RIDAGEYR", "RIDRETH1")]`

Thanks for your help.  If you want to re-enter it as the answer to my question, I'd be more than happy to mark this solved.  You should get the credit for solving it.

Comment: WRT names.tolower that's not really quite what I was aiming at.  Ideally there'd be an option to preserve case of all names as-is.  But that's superfluous to the problem at hand.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, per [**`SASxport::read.xport`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SASxport/versions/1.7.0/topics/read.xport) docs, this function reads one or more datasets depending on the SAS `.xpt` file. Therefore, this method operates at dataset level and not attributes within a single data frame and so `keep` argument limits dataset names not column names.

Consequently, you need to subset columns after import. If the return is a single dataset run extract function, `[` (which can take column name or column order number). Below show equivalent column subset methods:

```
test <- read.xport("DEMO_H.XPT")[c("SEQN", "RIAGENDR", "RIDAGEYR", "RIDRETH1")] 

test <- subset(read.xport("DEMO_H.XPT"), select=c(SEQN, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, RIDRETH1))
```

If the return is a list of *similarly structured* datasets, then run through an iterator like `lapply`:

```
test_dfs <- lapply(read.xport("DEMO_H.XPT"), "[", c("SEQN", "RIAGENDR", "RIDAGEYR", "RIDRETH1"))

test_dfs <- lapply(read.xport("DEMO_H.XPT"), subset, select=c(SEQN, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, RIDRETH1))
```

Comment: One follow-on for others who read this thread ... I used the version of `read.xport` from the package `SASxport`, not from package `foreign`.  The syntax seems to work identically.

Comment: Whoops! That was actually my typo though link pointed to correct package. Edited accordingly.